# php localhost Google_Client() fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode returns cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, google-oauth

I'm trying my first attempt at implementing a google-client oAuth authentication and have set up my google OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and have the following code:

```
    require_once 'autoload.php';

    $clientID=config::google_clientId;
    $clientSecret=config::google_clientsecret;
    $redirectUri=config::google_redirectUri;

    $client=new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($clientID);
    $client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("profile");

    if ( isset($_GET['code'])) {
        echo "<LI>74";
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
        echo "<LI>75";
        $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
```

but when the code gets to `$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);` I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token in C:\wamp64.......\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 211
> ( ! ) GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token in C:\wamp64.......\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 211
> Call Stack

as it's localhost why would I have a certificate, so what have I missed?

(WAMP PHP7.3; composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0")

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I've ditched this code and using the latest Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) and I'm now using the following

login page.php...

```
 $siteURL="....";
 $google_clientId=".....";

 echo "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src='https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client' async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='g_id_onload'
            data-client_id='$google_clientId'
            data-login_uri='$siteURL/login.php'
            data-auto_prompt='true'>
        </div>
        <div class='g_id_signin'
            data-type='standard'
            data-size='large'
            data-theme='outline'
            data-text='sign_in_with'
            data-shape='rectangular'
            data-logo_alignment='left'>
        </div>
    </body>
    <html>
 ";
```

login.php code...

```
 require_once 'autoload.php';
 .
 .
 .
 if (isset($_POST['credential'])) {
        $id_token = $_POST['credential'];
        $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $google_clientId]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend

        $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,),));
        $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

        $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
        if ($payload) {

             echo "<PRE>".print_r($payload, true)."</PRE>";
             .
             .
             .
             .
        }
        else {
            // Invalid ID token
        }
```